# Is It OK to Instantiate Multiple Instances of the Generic Host (IHost)

Tags: c#, .net, ihostedservice

We have a framework upon which my team builds microservice apps and related jobs.  We want to migrate it from using `IWebHost` for web apps and `IHost` for jobs to simply using `IHost` for both.  We haven't done so yet because of issues with DI.

Using `WebHostBuilder` and the `Startup` class, there was a way to build the services container, then use services in it to get values to bind to configuration, then rebuild the services container with the rest of the needed services.  We used this technique to "early-bind" our configuration service, use it to get settings from a data store, bind those to a typed `IOptions`, then bind the rest of the services, thus allowing them to receive, from the DI system, the `IOptions` we bound.

With `IHost`, there is no such "double DI" and so the jobs half of our framework has needed to jury-rig things to get those settings propagated throughout the apps (we can't bind them to `IOptions`).

So, my goal has been to identify how to use `IHost`, and still be able to register a service, call that service to get settings, bind those settings to `IOptions`, and let them be used throughout the rest of the app.  Today it occurred to me that maybe I could just create two instances of `IHost` in my `Main()` method.  This solution works, but my question is *are there any problems that could arise from doing this?*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tempHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
            })
            .Build();

        var configModel = tempHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfigService>().GetConfigModel();
        IConfigurationRoot? configurationRoot = null;
        tempHost.Dispose();

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
            {
                configurationRoot = builder.AddInMemoryCollection(GetSettings(configModel)).Build();
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>();
                services.AddTransient<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
                services.Configure<ConfigModel>(configurationRoot);
                services.AddTransient<IGoofballService, GoofballService>();
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetSettings(ConfigModel model)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var typeName = nameof(ConfigModel);

        dictionary.Add($"{typeName}:{nameof(model.Id)}", model.Id.ToString());
        dictionary.Add($"{typeName}:{nameof(model.Stamp)}", model.Stamp.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        return dictionary;
    }
```

Comment: What is `ConfigService`?

Comment: Also personally I would look into creating [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider).

Comment: @GuruStron - ConfigService is a stand-in for a service that has a method which returns an object (ConfigModel) containing all the settings (in this example, those are "Id" and "Stamp").  The idea is to call that service and bind the contents of the result to IOptions<ConfigModel>.

Comment: What exactly it does? Does it call database/some other service?

Comment: @GuruStron - The actual implementation is a service that ultimately uses an HttpClient to call to a separate endpoint to get config settings.